# App to view the 360° panorama pictures

Tags: gratis, macos, image-viewer

I've got 360° panorama pictures taken by [Gear 360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Gear_360) camera which I'd like to view on macOS.

These are standard JPEG files, but usually shown as spherical when opened.

For example, I have tried to open with *Preview.app*, but they just flat and spherical without the ability to see them by looking around.

Which app can I use to open these 360° panorama pictures?

---

The app should be not too heavy on memory and open pictures fairly quickly.

I expect it should have the feature to browse the panorama either using cursors or a mouse, similarly like when using *Google Street View*.

Ideally, it should be free to use, but I am open for suggestions.